# Couldn't bind deserialize Json objects into class model

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, deserialization, json-deserialization

after deserialize this Json, I'm not able to bind the objects into class model.

```
[{
    "products": {
        "prd10": null,
        "prd20": [
            {
                "pinno": "260158299582",
                "expirydate": "2019-12-31",
                "remark": "remark 1"
            }
        ],
        "prd30": [
            {
                "pinno": "782252223809",
                "expirydate": "2019-12-31",
                "remark": "remark 2"
            },
            {
                "pinno": "875928008089",
                "expirydate": "2019-12-31",
                "remark": "remark 3"
            }
        ],
        "user key": "333573536fbfe5164",
        "post date": "2019-07-24T17:43:56.888179+08:00"
    }
}]
```

---

```
public class products
{
    public List<prod_details> product{ get; set; }

}

public class prod_details
{
    public string pinno { get; set; }
    public string expirydate { get; set; }
    public string remark { get; set; }
}
```

> products myModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json_string);

I had tried with dynamic result, but still not able to retrieve the data.
Please help!

Comment: your classes do not match this JSON

Comment: `prd20`,`prd30` is `string` in `prod_details` class, but in `json` is `Array`

Comment: the class is an object not array and some values from the json object also 
you should specify the type in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<products>(json_string);

In order this to work Remove the [] on the root of the json object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the solution of this json deserialization :

***Note*** : *I have modified your array of **prd10, prd20** etc to common name like **prd** only otherwise it will return null model*.

**I have modified your Json Object like below** :

```
[{
"products": {
    "prd": null,
    "prd": [
        {
            "pinno": "260158299582",
            "expirydate": "2019-12-31",
            "remark": "remark 1"
        }
    ],
    "prd": [
        {
            "pinno": "782252223809",
            "expirydate": "2019-12-31",
            "remark": "remark 2"
        },
        {
            "pinno": "875928008089",
            "expirydate": "2019-12-31",
            "remark": "remark 3"
        }
    ],
    "user key": "333573536fbfe5164",
    "post date": "2019-07-17"
}
}]
```

**And you have to create model like below as per your Json Object** :

```
    public partial class ProductClass
    {
        [JsonProperty("products")]
        public Products Products { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Products
    {
        [JsonProperty("prd")]
        public List<Prd> Prd { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("user key")]
        public string UserKey { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("post date")]
        public DateTimeOffset PostDate { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Prd
    {
        [JsonProperty("pinno")]
        public string Pinno { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("expirydate")]
        public DateTimeOffset Expirydate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("remark")]
        public string Remark { get; set; }
    }
```

**Now you have to deserialize json object to class** :

```
string JsonObj = "[{ products: { prd: null, prd: [ { pinno: 260158299582, expirydate: '2019-12-31', remark: 'remark 1' } ], prd: [ { pinno: 782252223809, expirydate: '2019-12-31', remark: 'remark 2' }, { pinno: 875928008089, expirydate: '2019-12-31', remark: 'remark 3' } ], 'user key': '333573536fbfe5164', 'post date': '2019-07-17' } }]";
List<ProductClass> result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProductClass>>(JsonObj.ToString());
```

**Here is the snap of output** :

[image]

**Cheers** !!